# Do any schools maintain records of when instructors arrive and depart the classroom?

Tags: working-time

Recently, my college began placing staff around the school to record when instructors arrive. The record is to the second. A school announcement also warned against arriving late and ending lessons early by even fraction of a minute. I am somewhat surprised to find this in a tertiary institution. How common is this?

Comment: I've never heard of this kind of clock-punching setup before, but it doesn't necessarily seem like a bad thing. At the school where I teach, it is extremely common to have teachers teach significantly less than the number of hours they're hired to. For example, when I have a 10:30 class, and there's a class in the classroom before mine that is supposed to end at 10:20, it may happen that the instructor who does the earlier class is *always* done by 10:00. I also hear horror stories from my students about profs who miss literally half their classes, canceling by email each time.

Comment: "I am somewhat surprised to find this in a tertiary institution." I am not. Only a tertiary institution would have so much free cycles left to spare as to be able to pull this off, and faculty so unworthy for such a practice to be gainful in any sense. Decent institutions don't have to worry about stupid stuff like that.]

Comment: @Kuba I think "tertiary" here means third-level (i.e. college/university level), not third-class.

Comment: @user10529 In any case, the institution of such a policy makes the instituting institution a tertiary one, as in third-class :)

Answer (score 1):

I thinks it depends if the instructor is Tenured, part time or a contract instructor. For the later two, I would believe that the school would have some time sheet system for payroll purposes. Its becoming common. 
Temple university has a template for time sheet for instructors
http://www.temple.edu/cjtp/pdfs/Instructor%20Timesheet.pdf

Also, check out this link

http://www.nj.com/news/index.ssf/2011/02/kean_university_now_requires_f.html